# What are all options of writing a reactJS web page markup?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have tried ES6 but do not know the other options of writing a reactJs markup. Is ES6 the best option? I am curious of other options of writing the markup of reactJs web page and see what is the best option for me? Can you help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JSX is the syntax used for markup actually. ES6 is basically a prerequisite for development in reactJs and its recommended by their official documentation as some of the feature of ES6 are used in reactJs development. See here: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#prerequisites